# Placing button next to input in table row

Tags: html, css

This is what my table looks right now

Table:

[image: 1]

I'm trying to place the small x button aligned next to the input textbox. Here's my code so far.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <th>Clave</th>
        <th>Razón social</th>
        <th>Contacto 1</th>
        <th>Contacto 2</th>
        <th>Contacto 3</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td class="col-md-1">
            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" disabled/>
            <a title="Quitar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" disabled/>
            <a title="Quitar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" disabled/>
            <a title="Quitar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a title="Quitar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide CSS code as well. Your inputs probably have a width of 100% which causes the buttons to appear under them in a new line. You can try to minimize the width of the button from input with something like `input { width: calc(100% - 60px); }` also make sure the input is an `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what you're looking for

```css
td .btn {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 7px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
td input {
  float: left;
}
.spacer {
  padding-left: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <th>Clave</th>
        <th>Razón social</th>
        <th>Contacto 1</th>
        <th>Contacto 2</th>
        <th>Contacto 3</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td class="col-md-1">
            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" disabled/>
            <a title="Quitar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="spacer">
            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" disabled/>
            <a title="Quitar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="spacer">
            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" disabled/>
            <a title="Quitar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="spacer">
            <a title="Quitar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<td nowrap></td>
```

There is a CSS version of this:

```
th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't do anything